# Reusable constant/variable in Maven settings.xml configuration file

Tags: xml, maven, maven-3, settings

In my settings.xml I have:

```
<servers>
    <server>
      <username>MYUSERNAME</username>
      <password>MYPASSWORDHASH</password>
      <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>MYUSERNAME</username>
      <password>MYPASSWORDHASH</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
    ...
    <server>
      <username>MYUSERNAME</username>
      <password>MYPASSWORDHASH</password>
      <id>maven</id>
    </server>
</servers>
```

As you can see username and password are duplicated several times.
For convenience I would like to put them into constants and change them in only one place.

```
<some-tag-that-i-need>
  <MYUSERNAME_CONSTANT>MYUSERNAME</MYUSERNAME_CONSTANT>
  <MYPASSWORDHASH_CONSTANT>MYPASSWORDHASH</MYPASSWORDHASH_CONSTANT>
</some-tag-that-i-need>
<servers>
    <server>
      <username>${MYUSERNAME_CONSTANT}</username>
      <password>${MYPASSWORDHASH_CONSTANT}</password>
      <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>${MYUSERNAME_CONSTANT}</username>
      <password>${MYPASSWORDHASH_CONSTANT}</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
    ...
    <server>
      <username>${MYUSERNAME_CONSTANT}</username>
      <password>${MYPASSWORDHASH_CONSTANT}</password>
      <id>maven</id>
    </server>
</servers>
```

**Questions:**
1. Is it possible to declare such thing in Maven settings.xml file?
2. If not is there another way to get rid of such redundance?

Comment: Simple answer: This is not possible. I would assume you have different accounts for different purposes?

Comment: Thanks. No, I don't have different accounts for different purposes. The only problem is that I have to change password from time to time and thus replace it in many places in this file. I also wanted to write settings.xml file in the best way It is possible. Now I know that I can't do anything more to make it better. The only way to go further is to write a script which will replace old password automatically where the `<password>...</password>` tag is :) You might write your answer as an "real" answer, then I will accept it so other people seeking for the same thing could see it immediately.